# Is there a way for me to use my new page layout for just the people within my resource view?

Tags: developer

I've created a new page layout in my set up section under contacts.  Within my contacts, I have a view entitled resources.  Is there a way for me to use my new page layout for just the people within my resource view?

Comment: Are those contacts of a specific record type? If not, what distinguishes them from your other contacts? Are they related to Accounts of a unique type? I hope you see where I'm going with my questions.

Comment: They are all under the account name: Resources

Comment: Unless you had a specific record type or custom page that you only used for that Account using either a button or a link to that page which supplied the account Id so it could query the contacts, it would be difficult to do this. However, it would be easy to have a "List View" that's saved to show all the contacts related to that account. Is your page layout a detail page or is it a List View? Normally Detail Pages are assigned by profile or by record type is the issue.